# What is this plant with spikes of purple flowers?

Tags: identification

This plant came in a tub with some other flowers 2 years ago and looked like a hosta. However this spring it has suddenly sprung up like a triffid and I have no clue as to what it is.

<sub>*Click on photo for full size*</sub>
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're talking about the plant in the center? It looks like foxglove (digitalis), but I'm not sure of the variety. Very pretty!

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Would be cool if it is :)

Comment: Definitely foxglove.  Enjoy!  Just don't let pets or kids take a bit out of it, it's pretty poisonous.

Comment: thanks for letting me know and I am quite pleased as I never had one before.

Comment: Interesting foxglove - I saw your answer and thought "no its not!" until I looked more closely as the shape threw me off. The ones in my garden have the exact same flowers and leaves, but the leaves are far far sparser and much bigger compared to the overall plant size. I wonder if it is climate based variation or a different type.